# How can I add a private package from GitHub with my user and password to my pubspec.yaml?

Tags: github, flutter, package, yaml, password-protection

My question is simple. I can clone a private git repository using

```
git clone https://my_user_name:my_password@github.com/my_account/my_package.git
```

now, How can I add a private package from GitHub with my user and password to my pubspec.yaml?

```
dependencies:
  my_package:
    git: https://my_user_name:my_password@github.com/my_account/my_package.git
```

In my case, I am working with Flutter/Dart in IntelliJ IDEA.  But assume the solution should work on any environment and other programming languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, after test and test and test... found two good things:

First: We can use

```
dependencies:
  my_package:
    git: 
      url: https://my_user_name:my_password@github.com/my_account/my_package.git 
      ref: stable
      # ref: master or any other branch in your private package.
```

and with **ref**: we can select any branch by name.

**EDIT by Nov. 5, 2023**

Rather than "my_password" you must provide a valid token generated in your GitHub account.  See comments below.

Comment: what is my_account?

Comment: my_account is the name in GitHub of your account (or bussiness account).

Example:  In GitHub ther a repo: flutter/plugins
flutter is the account name. (in my answer is "my_account")
plugins is the repository name. (in my answer is "my_package")

Comment: Actually GitHub now does not allow to use a password ("my_password").  Now, we need to use a token.

Comment: Take the token as username and leave the password blank.

Comment: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.

Comment: It was not "removed", but deprecated.  Sure!  You have to provide a token rather than your password.  If you don't have a token, you can generate one for your GitHub account.  Then, click on your avatar and go to Settings -> Developer Settings -> Tokens (classic), then click on the "Generate new token" button.  You must provide the scope (what do you allow [permission]) for the new token.  It provides a lot of security.